# What is the most expensive item obtained from the Mixer in Wonderful 101?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

There is one item which costs 30 of each ingredient. All other items are health recovery items (the left panel) or attack all items I think (right panel, except the lowest). But the lowest item is nothing of the above. What is it? Below is a self-made picture of the mixer.

[image: Mixer image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That item in the bottom-right is a **Wonderful Card**, and is indeed by far the most useful item you can mix - it acts as a freebie for any one thing from the store. Something you want costs far more money than you have? Throw a Wonderful Card at it, and it's free. Mix as many as you can and use them on whatever the best or most expensinve thing available is; you get enough recovery items through the levels that you shouldn't really need to mix them yourself.